Django Email Sending Issue: Email Not Sent and Not Appearing in Sent Items
I'm working on a Django project where I need to send an email with an attached PDF file. My current setup is as follows:
Django Version: 4.0.3
Python Version: 3.12.2
Problem:
The code runs without throwing any errors.
However, the email is not being received by the recipient.
The email is also not appearing in the "Sent" folder of the sending Gmail account.
Things I've Tried:
Verified that the email configuration in settings.py is correct, using the Gmail SMTP server.
Checked that the PDF file exists at the specified path.
Ensured that there are no exceptions thrown during the email sending process.
Tried sending a simple email without attachment, but still no success.
Checked Gmail account security settings, including enabling "Less secure app access" and using an App Password.
Questions:
What might be causing the email to not be sent or appear in the sent items?
Are there any additional debugging steps I can take to figure out what's going wrong?
Could there be an issue with Gmail's SMTP server, or is there something I might be missing in the Django configuration?
def send_email(request, customer_id):
    try:
        order = customer_agent.objects.get(customer_id=customer_id)
    except customer_agent.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseNotFound("Order not found")

    subject = 'Your Order Details'
    message = 'Please find attached the PDF with your order details.'
    recipient_email = order.customer_email
    file_path = f"{settings.BASE_DIR}/orders_data/order_{customer_id}.pdf"

    mail = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=message, from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, to=[recipient_email])
    mail.attach_file(file_path)

    try:
        mail.send()
        print("Email sent successfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to send email: {e}")
        return HttpResponse(f"Failed to send email: {e}")

    return HttpResponse("Email sent successfully!")


mail.send() return 1? or other?

it is showing somekind of hash value

On your settings try adding
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

instead of
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'

and check if the email is printed on the console or not.If the email is printed on the console there must be error on your settings. Ensure these variables are correct
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-email@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-email-app-password'


MIME-Version: 1.0
Subject: Your Order Details
From: ski####@gmail.com
To: bo####@gmail.com
Date: Tue, 13 Aug 2024 10:04:29 -0000
Message-ID: <172354346958.################>
0894516969042778278
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Please find attached the PDF with your order details.
0894516969042778278==
Content-Type: application/pdf
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="order_682563.pdf"
BvcnRsYWIuY29tCjEgMCBvYmoKPDwKL0Y9
then this type of value starts prninting

Ok this means your logic on code is correct since it printed the mail content on the console now change the email backend to django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
and verify these parameters are correct
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-email@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-email-app-password'

Yes, all the parameters are correct. I'm running the app on a local server, which means I haven't deployed it on a remote server yet. Is this the reason for the issue?
